# Anaconda installation trouble for mac osx

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Quick question to try and find out what I'm doing wrong for installing anaconda on mac osx. I've downloaded the version for python 3.5, but when I try to open and run the file it just opens in textedit with a bunch of symbols. A sample of what appears in the text editor:

xar! (± ÆB x⁄îWY”¢H≥æ7¬ˇ–—Á“ò \&ﬁÓâbG e ÔX§dW ¸ı_È€o˜7=}ŒÃπ0ÑL2+´2ü'≥ﬁ˛ ‚”˝‹¥i]}˘L˛N|˛tÆ¢:N+¯Â≥cãø≠?ˇ˘uÚ6 Õ◊…ß∑Æéﬂß∑®9 ∂¯≠KÀÛWä ◊ø Ão cìÙ ÃÍ äyõˇıìó—Â Âm_~jª±8 ˘‹^ ÚÛSÛÈ≠Níˆ‹}%ﬁÊﬂû^“6}<ùøÕ_ O Û Ø∑6ÖU–ıÕ˘√£iÅø:§~ÈëY˛p˘Èmw ï*©?·É®⁄/ü/]w˝c>G ˝é ø◊
úS AÃâÕ „%ˇÁ}âOo

Do I not have something updated correctly? I also notice that within Finder -> Downloads, where the file is located, under the "Kind" column is says document, when in the installing videos I've watched it says install package. So maybe it's not even downloading correctly. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This sample seems to be sth. in malbolge!

Comment: I would recommend running the following in your terminal: `brew cask install anaconda`. If you don't have `brew` installed (you should), go here first: https://brew.sh/

Comment: @PMende Thanks. I tried and realized I do not have brew installed, so I will start with that.

Comment: I'm guessing it's an XAR archive. Open your terminal and type the following: `cd /Users/nate/Downloads`; `mkdir anaconda`, then `xar -x -C anaconda -f yourfilename`